# How to get an overview of all android attributes at runtime?

Tags: android, android-studio, attributes, styles, themes

Let's start with the practical example. When styling a button Android Studio IDE may give the warning, that a button should be borderless and I should apply `?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle` to reach this.

The attributes are a kind of variables. I want to know, what this attribute is resolving to at runtime, to get a deeper insight into those style.

This bring me to the general question, how do I access the values that the attributes hold at runtime. They live in the scope of styles and themes. Right?

Is there an easy way to get an overview? Are the values cached somewhere? Does any IDE provides a window to see them? Or is my only option to track them by use of a debugger?

Sorry, if this question isn't a new one. It's always difficult to find old answers for very general search terms. They are not specific enough to select usable results.

Answer (score 0):

To give a part of the answer myself. I found an option to see at least the value of ONE attribute, the attribute if was interested in, but not a listing tool of all attributes.

When I click in the designer window upon the ellipsis of a property a window with related resources pops up. I use the search input to find the attribute (buttonBarButtonStyle in this case). This brings up the informations I am interested in.

`?attr/buttonBarButtonStyle => @style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog`

Now I am amused that following the track from a regular button leads me to the style of an AlertDialog. I always thought CSS is messy ...

[image]